# 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer? error when uploading

Tags: macos, app-store, signing, submission

I'm trying to upload my App to the Mac App Store and when I'm uploading it via Application Uploader I get an error :

> > The product archive package's signature is invalid. Ensure that it is signed with your "3rd Party Mac Developer Installers" certificate. (1091)

but I ran

```
codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Thomas Olson" "/Users/Tom/Dropbox/MyGame.app"
```

&

```
productbuild --component "/Users/Tom/Dropbox/MyGame.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Thomas Olson" MyGame.pkg
```

Terminal says everything went fine.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the "Archive" functionality within Xcode? I believe it both signs packages for you as well as runs checks after to make sure that the signing process worked (just because the console app completed without errors doesn't mean that the certificate used to sign it was current, configured correctly, etc.)